# Обработка событий JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

можно ли переопределить обработчик события `mouseleave` при наведении на элемент `a`. А после, при наведении на `hover`, вернуть его в то же состояние.

```
<div id=example>
<div class=hover></div>
<div class=place></div>
</div>


/*CSS*/
#example {
  width:400px;
  height:600px;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
.hover {
  width:90%;
  height:10%;
  background-color:#c0c0c0;
}

a {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
}

/*JS*/
$('<a href=http://google.ru target=_blank>Click Me</a>').insertAfter('.place');

$('.hover').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('a').show();
});

$('.hover').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('a').hide();
});
```

Сейчас при наведении курсора на элемент `а`, выполняется событие `$('.hover').on('mouseleave')`, которое соответственно его скрывает. 
Я хочу отменить это действие, но скрыть элемент `a` нужно при выходе курсора из `.hover`
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obYBVJ

Comment: можете словами описать поведение какое вы хотите? сейчас не совсем понятно, что в итоге должно получиться

Comment: Поправил вопрос.

Comment: можете посмотреть в сторону событий _mouseover_, _mouseout_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть одноименный метод https://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);
```

или

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

или css добавить правило

```
.hover:hover ~ a , a:hover{
  display:block;  
}
```

вот как выглядит https://jsfiddle.net/r3pqqw94/4/

Comment: `$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );` уже используется в самом вопросе

Comment: Был не внимателен

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем решилось просто добавлением обработчика на `a`

```
$('.hover').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('a').show();
});

$('a').hover(function() {
            $(this).show();
});

$('.hover').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('a').hide();
});
```

Comment: Можно было просто css обновил свой ответ

Comment: если бы css еще и удалять элементы из DOM умел, то цены бы ему не было.